# How can I get records using a random Start Date and End Date when a certain Column (OrganizationID) changes every year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ResourceID  is the ID number of the Resource
OrganizationId is the current Organization or Department of the Resource
Effective Date is the start date or the first day of the Resource in that Organization
```

As you can see on the select query below, the OrganizatioID of the example Resource changes based on the Effective Date column.

```
select * from ResourceOrganization 
where ResourceID = 'vc1976'

ResourceID  OrganizationID  EffectiveDate   
VC1976      INTIN1HTHWYAMM  1995-07-10 00:00:00.000  
VC1976      VNMVN1HTHWYAMM  2009-07-01 00:00:00.000  
VC1976      INTIN1HTHWYAMM  2009-12-23 00:00:00.000  
VC1976      INTIN1LGAMMAMS  2011-07-01 00:00:00.000  
VC1976      SMESM1HTOVEOVE  2012-07-01 00:00:00.000  
VC1976      APCAP1HTOVEOVE  2012-07-09 10:17:56.000
```

This is my actual query below. Obviously it will give me wrong answer because I am selectively putting the @OrganizationID, @StartDate and @EndDate. 
The organizationiD **INTIN1LGAMMAMS** for ResourceID **VC1976** began on **2011-07-01** and ends on **2012-06-30**. But what if the user inputs a startdate and end date out of **2011-07-01** and ends on **2012-06-30**? See my example (actual query) below.

```
Declare @OrganizationID nvarchar(30)
Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime


set @OrganizationID = 'INTIN1LGAMMAMS'
set @StartDate = '2013-10-01'
set @EndDate = '2013-12-01'

Select  ro.ResourceID, ro.OrganizationID, ro.EffectiveDate, t.TimeEntryDate 
from ResourceOrganization ro
left outer join Time t
on ro.ResourceID = t.ResourceID
where t.TimeEntryDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and ro.OrganizationID = @OrganizationID
```

Below are the results of this query which is wrong because the Resource **VC1976** doesn't suppose to have any Time Entries between **2013-10-01** and **2013-12-01** under the OrganizationUnit  INTIN1LGAMMAMS at that period of time, because the Resource was only under organizationID  **INTIN1LGAMMAMS** between **2011-07-01** and ends on **2012-06-30**. Because ResourceID VC1976 already belongs to APCAP1TOVEOVE based from the StartDate and EndDate that the user put in the parameter. My Stored proc should have an OrganizationID, StartDate and EndDate parameters so I cannot remove any of it.

```
ResourceID  OrganizationID  EffectiveDate             TimeEntryDate
VC1976     INTIN1LGAMMAMS   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000   2013-10-01 00:00:00.000
VC1976     INTIN1LGAMMAMS   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000   2013-10-02 00:00:00.000
VC1976     INTIN1LGAMMAMS   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000   2013-10-02 00:00:00.000
VC1976     INTIN1LGAMMAMS   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000   2013-10-03 00:00:00.000
VC1976     INTIN1LGAMMAMS   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000   2013-10-03 00:00:00.000
VC1976     INTIN1LGAMMAMS   2011-07-01 00:00:00.000   2013-10-03 00:00:00.000
```

Can any one help me solve this? It should only give all the lists of ResourceIDs that belongs to that OrganizationID in that period of time based on what the user has put in the StartDate and EndDate parameter.

Comment: Im not sure if this is correct. your Ideas are most welcome.

Comment: You are not showing us what the Time table looks like and what data is in it. Perhaps you could create a SQLfiddle with your tables, some sample data, and the SQL, then people are likely to understand you better and provide a solution.

Comment: I think this help it solve, correct me if I am wrong. 
Case when ro.OrganizationID <> @ OrganizationID then @ OrganizationID else @ OrganizationID end,

Comment: Can you show the correct results that you do want?

Comment: Your question will be incomplete without Time table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to limit the selection of ResourceOrganization by EffectiveDate. Try this:

```
Select  ro.ResourceID, ro.OrganizationID, ro.EffectiveDate, t.TimeEntryDate 
from ResourceOrganization ro
left outer join Time t
on ro.ResourceID = t.ResourceID
where t.TimeEntryDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and ro.OrganizationID = @OrganizationID
and ro.EffectiveDate = (
  select max(EffectiveDate)
  from ResourceOrganization
  where ResourceID = ro.ResourceID
  and EffectiveDate < @EndDate)
```

Comment out the `and ro.OrganizationID = @OrganizationID` line (or change the value of `@ OrganizationID` to another value) to obtain some output with the given data.

[Here is the SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94c0e/5).

Comment: But how can I see the Time Entries of each Resource?
Here are the results. There should be a fourth column after ro.EffectiveDate which indicates each time entries based form the STartDate and EndDate

ResourceID OrganizationID EffectiveDate
AK10148         SMESM1HTOVEOVE 2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
GG1778         SMESM1HTOVEOVE 2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
GS1883         SMESM1HTOVEOVE 2013-04-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: Your problem is difficult to understand. As I asked above, you should create a SQLfiddle so others can understand your problem and provide a solution. [Here is my fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94c0e/5). I have revised my answer accordingly.